# Assign Products to Specific Store Programmatically : Magento2

Tags: magento2, products, stores, magento2.4.1

I am trying to assign different products of the main store to other stores programmatically. Is there any way to get it done?

Comment: You have different websites? We can set different data for the different stores in same website. Are you trying to move products from one website to another website's store?

Comment: Please clarify here so i can answer you question.

Comment: @ZealousWeb, i have a website which can have multiple stores, each store can contain different products.
For example, a user will chose which product he wants to add to his store. 
So, is there any method which makes this possibility

Comment: There will be one main store, from where the products will be assigned to different stores